# Project Euler 8: Getting Incorrect Answer From Code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently trying to do some of the Project Euler questions. I'm currently on [question 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) and I'm using python to solve it.

I made some code and got an answer, which turns out to be **incorrect**. I'm not sure what the problem is with my code, so I'd be grateful is someone could tell me what the issue is. I'm getting an answer of 56435097600, which is the 13 numbers multiplied together on the 30th column with an offset of 6, so it starts 7894... Here's my code, it's not very efficient or neat, but I just want to know what the issue is, not change my code to make it neater/more effective.

```
rows = ['73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934','96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843','85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511',
        '12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557','66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113','62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749',
        '30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866','70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776','65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243',
        '52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397','53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482','83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474',
        '82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881','16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586','17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042',
        '24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408','07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188','84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606',
        '05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725','71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450',]

columns  = []

def createcolumns():

    global rows,columns

    for x in range(0,50):
        tempvalue = ''
        for j in range(0,20):
            tempvalue = tempvalue + rows[j][x]
        columns.append(tempvalue)

def multiply(string):
    tempvalue = 1
    for letters in string:
        tempvalue *= int(letters)
    return tempvalue


def highestnumber():

    global rows,columns

    highest = 0

    # 37 ways per row * 20 + 7 ways per column * 50

    for x in range(0,20):
        for g in range(0,37):
            tempvalue = ''
            for j in range(0,13):
                tempvalue = tempvalue + rows[x][j+g]
            tempvalue = multiply(tempvalue)
            if(tempvalue > highest):
                highest = tempvalue

    for x in range(0,50):
        for g in range(0,7):
            tempvalue = ''
            for j in range(0,13):
                tempvalue = tempvalue + columns[x][j+g] 
            tempvalue = multiply(tempvalue)
            if(tempvalue > highest):
                highest = tempvalue

    return highest

createcolumns()
print(highestnumber())
```

Output:

```
>> 56435097600
```

Comment: That takes out the fun of project euler! The point is to solve them yourself. See the [about page](https://projecteuler.net/about)

Comment: @sacul I'm just really not sure what I've done wrong. I don't want people to recode everything, I just want to know what's the issue; I really can't tell what I've done wrong. Although, it's probably going to be something really obvious.

Comment: If your function is outputting something, but that is the wrong something, the issue is not really with the program, but with what the program is doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the purpose is to solve this yourself.
However, I would like to point out the flaw in your understanding of this question and you can pick up from there.
The question talks about a "1000 digit" number.
That means, all the 20 rows of 50 digits need to be merged into 1 single number of 1000 digits.
It's been given in a matrix form just for good visibility.
So approaching this problem with rows X columns may not help.
Your logic would work well for the 4 digit number since it is all in 1 row.
And since your logic's failing for a 13 digit number, my guess is that the 13 digits do not fall in 1 single row.
If I'm not wrong.

Comment: Oh. I can't believe I didn't realise that... Thanks so much